# Union and Intersection of intervals

Tags: intervals

I have two sets $A = \{1 \leq x \leq 5\}$ and $B = \{5 \leq x \leq 8\}$. Now I want to find the `Union` and `Intersection` of $A$ and $B$.

I tried `Union[A, B]`, I got `{1 <= x <= 5, 5 <= x <= 8}` and for `Intersection[A, B]`, I got `{}`. The correct  answer for  $A \cup B$ is `[1, 8]` and $A \cap B$ is `{5}`. How do I tell *Mathematica* to do that?

And if $A = \{1 < x < 5\}$ and $B = \{x > 5\}$. Now I want to find the `Union` and `Intersection` of $A$ and $B$.  How do I tell *Mathematica* to do that?

Comment: You will want to use `Interval`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
a = Interval[{1, 5}];
b = Interval[{5, 8}];
IntervalUnion[a, b]
```

> Interval[{1, 8}]

```
IntervalIntersection[a, b]
```

> Interval[{5, 5}]

Comment: `Interval[{1,5},{5,8}]` also gives `IntervalUnion[a,b]`  (+1)

Comment: Nice. I wasn't aware of that.

Comment: If A = {1 < x < 5} and B = {x > 1}. How must I do?

Comment: @minthao: `B = Interval[{1, ∞}]`.

Comment: If A = {1 < x < 5} and B= {x > 5}, then Intersection A and B is the empty set, 

A = Interval[{1, 5}];
B = Interval[{5, \[Infinity]}];
IntervalIntersection[A, B] 
Mathematica out put Interval[{5, 5}]

Comment: @minthao.  Mathematica seems to work only with closed intervals.  `Interval[{1,5]` includes the numbers 1 and 5, and therefore does not match your original inequality, 1<x<5. I don't know whether there is a way to not include the end points.  Perhaps this is a question worth asking.

Comment: @DavidCarraher I believe that the design objectives for `Interval` are focused to ease the implementation of interval arithmetic (an area of numerical analysis). See, for example, http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/IntervalArithmetic.html

Comment: @MarkMcClure Yes, it seems well equipped for dealing with issues of precision.  I was thinking more of the logic of intervals in pure mathematics, I suppose.

Comment: My idea is solve Solve[{(x - 1)*(x - 5) < 0, x - 1 > 0}, {x}]

Comment: @minthao_2011  For some reason that code does not work.

Comment: Can I post a new question about this problem?

Comment: Go right ahead. Did you notice that I already posted a follow-up question?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/5988/discussion-between-minthao-2011-and-david-carraher)

Answer (score 2):

Open/closed intervals compatible with regions:

```
OpenInterval[a_, b_] := ImplicitRegion[a < x && x < b, {x}];
ClosedInterval[a_, b_] := ImplicitRegion[a <= x && x <= b, {x}];
```

Semi-open intervals and infinity intervals are similar.

Need some typing to transform region to an expression:

- open intervals:

  ```
  RegionMember[RegionUnion[OpenInterval[0, 5], OpenInterval[5, 8]], {x}] // FullSimplify
  ```

  gives:

  ```
  x \[Element] Reals && (0 < x < 5 || 5 < x < 8)
  ```
- closed intervals:

  ```
  RegionMember[RegionUnion[ClosedInterval[0, 5], ClosedInterval[5, 8]], {x}] // FullSimplify
  ```

  gives:

  ```
  0 <= x <= 8
  ```

Comment: +1. That approach works in higher dimensions.

Comment: And also works for `Integers` instead of `Reals`.