# Can Mathematica Handle Open Intervals? Interval complements?

Tags: numerics, intervals

**Open Intervals**

Following up on [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11342/union-and-intersection-of-intervals/11343#comment34196_11343), I was wondering whether Mma can handle open intervals. For example,  the union of the intervals, $$1<x<5$$ 
and $$5<x<8$$

should not include the number 5. This is easy enough to do in one's head, but how can it be done, if at all, computationally?

**Interval Complement**

Also, is there a way to find the complement of two intervals? `IntervalComplement[int1,int2,int3]` should contain all the points in `int1`
that are **not** in the other intervals.

---

Edit:

Let's take Mark McClure's data as an example.

```
int1 = x < -2 || -1 <= x < 1 || x == 3 || 4 < x <= Pi^2;
int2 = -3 <= x < 0 || x > 1;
```

The intervals are shown below:

[image: intervals]

The Interval Complement (drawn above in blue on the x-axis) would seem to be:

```
x < -3 || 0 <= x < 1
```

Comment: Read this thread http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2006/Oct/msg00258.html

Comment: @belisarius  Yes,  Andrzej Kozlowski's `IntervalComplement` does work for closed intervals. Very nice!  It seems like his code does not handle open intervals, relying, as it does, on `Interval` for input.

Comment: Read thru the end :) http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2006/Oct/msg00347.html

Comment: I have now read through to the end. I did not feel that anything was resolved. I did not find compelling the attempted explanation of IntervalComplement's inherent contradiction.  Furthermore, the discussions about inclusion or not of endpoints in intervals was biased by the fact that mms does not (apparently) recognize open intervals.  Would you like to present your take on the discussion?

Comment: I had have a little domestic accident and I'm typing single handed and painfully. Perhaps tomorrow,sorry.

Comment: @belisarius Ouch. :-(  I hope you heal soon!

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks! Painful, but no risk. I'm typing at _turtle_ speed.

Comment: I would like to point out that Mathematica is quite gracious in handling Interval compliments. Moreover it thinks you have nice intervals, too.

Comment: Could you tell me that  which software did you use to draw the graph.Thanks a lot:)

Comment: I used Mathematica v.9 (or v. 8).  I must have drawn everything "by hand".  If I were to do it with v.10, I would use `NumberLinePlot[{{-\[Infinity] < x < -2, -1 < x <= 1, 4 < x <= Pi^2}},
  x]` and so forth.

Comment: $\infty$ is the valid symbol for infinity in the community. This is written a $ sign at the beginning and the end and '\infty' in between.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I'd represent the sets using inequalities and/or equalities and then apply `Reduce`.  Here's an example:

```
set1 = x < -2 || -1 <= x < 1 || x == 3 || 4 < x <= Pi^2;
set2 = -3 <= x < 0 || x > 1;
Reduce[set1 && set2]
```

[image]

Here's the complement of the union of the two intervals.

```
Reduce[!(set1 || set2)]

(* Out: x==1 *)
```

We might define an interval complement function as follows:

```
intervalComplement[bigInt_, moreInts__] := 
  Reduce[bigInt && (! (Or @@ {moreInts}))];
```

For example:

```
intervalComplement[-10 < x <= 10, -8 < x <= -6, 
  0 <= x <= 2, x == 3]
(* Out: -10 < x <= -8 || -6 < x < 0 || 2 < x < 3 || 3 < x <= 10 *)
```

Comment: You might want to take a look at the explanation and picture I placed in the question.

Comment: @DavidCarraher I did. I also checked that my `intervalComplement` gave your desired answer.

Comment: Very nice solution. It handles open intervals!

Comment: @MarkMcClure, is there a WL function to map `Interval` to algebraic expresssion and back to `Interval`?

Comment: @alancalvitti There is no such function that I know of, though it should be quite easy to create one using patterns.  Something like `toInequality[Interval[{a_,b_}], var_] := a<var<b`. Then, for example, `toInequality[Interval[{1, 2}], x]` returns `1<x<2`. Of course, you'd still need to decide whether you want open or closed intervals or some combination depending on the situation.

Comment: @MarkMcClure, but `Interval` also handles interval sets eg `Interval[{1,2},{3,4}]`. I think the built in Interval should map to closed sets - it's the inverse  map from the algebra back that's a problem, there should be suport for variants like `Interval[{1,Except[2]}]` or similar, for semi-open intervals etc.

Comment: @alancalvitti True - but, again, I don't think it's hard to roll your own depending on your needs.

Comment: @MarkMcClure, I think it's hard to make this generalization transparent to the relational operations like `IntervalIntersection` etc.

Answer (score 13):

Here's an implementation of interval complement that is meant to be used with [`Interval`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Interval.html) expressions.  `Interval` represents closed intervals according to the documentation, and this is consistent with the things the built-in functions do with intervals.  However, in this implementation of the interval complement I simply ignore whether an interval is open or closed.  I realize that this is not exactly what you asked for.  I wrote this because I needed it, and I thought it'd be useful to post it.

---

```
intervalInverse[Interval[int___]] := 
  Interval @@ 
    Partition[
      Flatten @ {int} /.
        {{-∞, mid___, ∞} :> {    mid   },
         {-∞, mid__    } :> {    mid, ∞},
         {    mid__,  ∞} :> {-∞, mid   },
         {    mid___   } :> {-∞, mid, ∞}},
      2
    ]

intervalComplement[a_Interval, b__Interval] := 
 IntervalIntersection[a, intervalInverse @ IntervalUnion[b]]
```

`intervalInverse[a]` will compute the complement $(-\infty, \infty) \setminus a$.

`intervalComplement[a,b,c,...]` will compute $a \setminus (b \cup c \cup \ldots )$.

---

Example usage:

```
In[]:= intervalInverse[Interval[{1, 2}]]
Out[]= Interval[{-∞, 1}, {2, ∞}]

In[]:= intervalComplement[Interval[{0, 10}], Interval[{2, 3}]]
Out[]= Interval[{0, 2}, {3, 10}]
```

Comment: Nice. It surprises me that something like this is not native to Mathematica, yet.

Comment: @DavidCarraher My guess is that it's not implemented because the complement of two closed intervals is going to be an open interval, which can't be represented using `Interval` (if we keep the assumption that it always represents a closed ones).  I was sloppy and ignored all this because it didn't matter for my application.  That sloppyness results in things like this `intervalInverse@intervalInverse[Interval[{1, 1}]] --> Interval[]`.  By taking the "inverse" twice I lost the endpoints of this zero-length non-empty closed interval and ended up with an empty interval.

Comment: Yes, but is an empty interval any stranger than an empty set? Granted, it is an interval without location.  On the other hand, an empty set is a set with no elements.

Comment: @Szabolcs, `Interval[{0,1}] ~ IntervalIntersection ~ Interval[{2,3}]` ==> `Interval[]`, empty interval.

Answer (score 3):

This is my code

```
{a = x > 1 && x < 5, b = x > 5 && x < 8}
{Reduce[a && b]}
```

and

```
{a = x > 1 && x < 5, b = x >= 5 && x < 8}
{Reduce[a || b]}
```

**Edit**

Some examples

```
{a = x > 0 && x < 3, b = x > -1 && x < 2, c = x > -2 && x < 1} {Reduce[a && (b || c)],
Reduce[(a && b) || (a && c)], Reduce[a || (b && c)], Reduce[(a || b) && (a || c)]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Open/closed intervals compatible with regions:

```
OpenInterval[a_, b_] := ImplicitRegion[a < x && x < b, {x}];
ClosedInterval[a_, b_] := ImplicitRegion[a <= x && x <= b, {x}];
```

Semi-open intervals and infinity intervals are the same.

Need some typing to transform region to an expression:

- open intervals:

  ```
  RegionMember[RegionUnion[OpenInterval[0, 5], OpenInterval[5, 8]], {x}] // FullSimplify
  ```

  gives:

  ```
  x \[Element] Reals && (0 < x < 5 || 5 < x < 8)
  ```
- closed intervals:

  ```
  RegionMember[RegionUnion[ClosedInterval[0, 5], ClosedInterval[5, 8]], {x}] // FullSimplify
  ```

  gives:

  ```
  0 <= x <= 8
  ```