# For a given expression: if it appears, remove it, but if it is absent, add it

Tags: list-manipulation, programming, replacement

While reformatting Szabolcs's code from [(42660)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/42660/121) I noticed this interesting operation:

```
expr /.
  {{-∞, mid___, ∞} :> {    mid   },
   {-∞, mid___   } :> {    mid, ∞},
   {    mid___, ∞} :> {-∞, mid   },
   {    mid___   } :> {-∞, mid, ∞}}
```

Essentially if a given expression (`-∞`) at the beginning of a List is present, remove it, but if it is absent, add it.  Likewise for `∞` at the end of the list.  An empty list `{}` should become `{-∞, ∞}`, while `{-∞, ∞}` itself should become `{}`.  Examples:

```
Replace[
  {{1, 2, 3}, {-∞, 1, 2}, {1, 2, ∞}, {-∞, 1, 2, ∞}, {-∞, ∞}, {∞}, {-∞}, {}},

  {{-∞, mid___, ∞} :> {    mid   },
   {-∞, mid___   } :> {    mid, ∞},
   {    mid___, ∞} :> {-∞, mid   },
   {    mid___   } :> {-∞, mid, ∞}},

  {1}
]
```

> ```
> {{-∞, 1, 2, 3, ∞}, {1, 2, ∞}, {-∞, 1, 2}, {1, 2}, {}, {-∞}, {∞}, {-∞, ∞}}
> ```

How might this operation be done with a single replacement rule, or cleanly with a different method?

Comment: Right, I need a coffee :)

Comment: Never mind project Euler, how about project Wizard?

Comment: @bobthechemist I'm not sure what that means really :-)

Comment: Paraphrasing the [project euler](https://projecteuler.net/) website, I would propose that "The motivation for <answering your questions>, is to provide a platform for the inquiring mind to delve into unfamiliar areas and learn new <Mathematica> concepts in a fun and recreational context."  Granted, I found it wittier before I tried to explain it.

Comment: @bobthechemist Sorry for making you explain, but at least I understand now.  Thanks. :-)

Comment: @bobthechemist Oh by the way: [rib rib](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/30646/121).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me relax rules a bit just to write some compact code without external functions. I can add `-∞` and `∞` and delete double infinities

```
Replace[{{1, 2, 3}, {-∞, 1, 2}, {1, 2, ∞}, {-∞, 1, 2, ∞}, {-∞, ∞}, {∞}, {-∞}, {}}, 
  {mid___} :> ({-∞, mid, ∞} /. {x_, x_, y___} :> {y} /. {y___, x_, x_} :> {y}), {1}]
(* {{-∞, 1, 2, 3, ∞}, {1, 2, ∞}, {-∞, 1, 2}, {1, 2}, {}, {-∞}, {∞}, {-∞, ∞}} *)
```

Comment: Thank you.  I'm not sure I can consider this more clean than the original but like it nevertheless.

Comment: I am accepting this because it is the only alternative posted that I would use in practice.

Answer (score 6):

Similar approach to Mr Wizard's but using a silly trick with pure functions rather than the auxiliary function `f`:

```
Replace[{{1, 2, 3}, {-∞, 1, 2}, {1, 2, ∞}, {-∞, 1, 2, ∞}, {-∞, ∞}, {∞}, {-∞}, {}},
  {a : (-∞ | PatternSequence[]), Shortest[x___], b : (∞ | PatternSequence[])} :> 
   {#2 &[a, Unevaluated[], -∞], x, #2 &[b, Unevaluated[], ∞]},
 {1}]
```

Answer (score 5):

I set out to condense the rules shown in the question by use of "vanishing patterns" but I found it rather difficult.  The best I could come up with is this:

```
f[x_ | __] := x

Replace[
 {{1, 2, 3}, {-∞, 1, 2}, {1, 2, ∞}, {-∞, 1, 2, ∞}, {-∞, ∞}, {∞}, {-∞}, {}},
 {a : -∞ ..., Shortest[s___], b : ∞ ...} :> {f[a, -∞], s, f[b, ∞]},
 {1}
]
```

> ```
> {{-∞, 1, 2, 3, ∞}, {1, 2, ∞}, {-∞, 1, 2}, {1, 2}, {}, {-∞}, {∞}, {-∞, ∞}}
> ```

I find this less than clean due to the need for auxiliary function `f`.  Further this requires that the input have at most one matching expression at the head or tail, otherwise e.g. `{1, 2, ∞, ∞}` will result in both `∞` being removed.  This can be corrected by replacing e.g. `∞ ...` with `Repeated[∞, {0, 1}]` at the expense of yet longer code. (See: [Function with zero or one arguments](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/47833/function-with-zero-or-one-arguments/47844#47844).)

Comment: I was just looking at something similar, but using `a : Longest[(-Infinity | PatternSequence[])]` as the head/tail patterns

Comment: @Simon I variation I hadn't considered.  Post it if you like.

Answer (score 3):

```
expr = {{1, 2, 3}, {-∞, 1, 2}, {1, 2, ∞}, {-∞, 1, 2, ∞}, {-∞, ∞}, {∞}, {-∞}, {}};
```

Not general but useful:

```
Flatten[Replace[Split[{-∞, ##, ∞}], {x_, x_} :> Sequence[], {1}]] & @@@ expr
```

Not working if in the list are repeated elements already.

Also `Flatten` should be restricted if we are dealing with more complex structures.

Comment: No, this merely *adds* the given elements at the beginning and end.  Note that the operation must also *remove* the elements in the case they appear.  It is not merely a matter of removing duplicates.  Thanks for taking interest however. :-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Ok, updated:)

Comment: I quite like this and I'm glad you posted it. (+1) However note that even in the original application this might not work since `Interval` can have duplicates, e.g. `Interval[{1, 3}, {7, 11}, {22, 22}]`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard good point.

Answer (score 1):

The most clean formulation, I believe, is “add an element and delete a pair if one occures”. Thus, I would just use something similar to

```
idempotentAppend[{most___, x_}, x_] := {most};
idempotentAppend[l_List, x_] := Append[l, x];
idempotentPrepend[{x_, most___}, x_] := {most};
idempotentPrepend[l_List, x_] := Prepend[l, x]
```

with “idempotent” in the $P^2=\mathrm{id}$ sense.

As for “single rule” solutions, this is the best one I came up with:

```
Replace[ {-∞, ##, ∞} & @@@
         {{1, 2, 3}, {-∞, 1, 2}, {1, 2, ∞}, {-∞, 1, 2, ∞}, {-∞, ∞}, {∞}, {-∞}, {}}
, Thread[{ PatternSequence[-∞, -∞] | PatternSequence[-∞, -∞] | PatternSequence[]
         , most___
         , PatternSequence[∞, ∞] | PatternSequence[] | PatternSequence[∞, ∞]}
  , Alternatives] :> {most}
, {1}]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is merely to participate. Just bookending and removing  doubled ups...

```
f[x_] := Fold[#1 /. #2 &, 
  Join[{-Infinity}, 
   x, {Infinity}], {{-Infinity, -Infinity, m___} :> {m}, {m___, 
     Infinity, Infinity} :> {m}}]
```

so,

```
w = {{1, 2, 3}, {-∞, 1, 2}, {1, 2, ∞}, {-∞, 1, 2, ∞}, {-∞, ∞}, {∞}, {-∞}, {}}
f /@ w
```

yields:

```
{{-∞, 1, 2, 3, ∞}, {1, 2, ∞}, {-∞, 1, 2}, {1, 2}, {}, {-∞}, {∞}, {-∞, ∞}}
```

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I accept my answer is rather uninspiring. May I ask how isthe infinity symbol appearance in most answers and similarly Greek characters? I am obviously missing something...just issue of readability and my ignorance.

Comment: I am using this toolbar extension: [(1043)](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1043/121).  Also useful: [(1137)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1137/121)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard thank you that is helpful and I look forward to effectively using toolbar extension :)