# How can I exclude endpoints of intervals?

Tags: intervals

I have list of intervals:

```
Jintervals = {Interval[{18.9, 21.}], Interval[{21., 23.1}]}
```

I need to exclude the endpoints - [18.9,21.), [21.,23.1)

Wrong -

```
IntervalMemberQ[Jintervals[[1]], 21]

(* True *)

IntervalMemberQ[Jintervals[[2]], 21]

(* True *)
```

Thanks.

Comment: `Interval` does not support open intervals. Nevertheless, what would you like to do with those open intervals if you had them? Perhaps we could find a way around it that still works for you.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: @MarcoB I am building a distribution function of continuous random variable

Comment: @PiPiPARU OK, and how do the open intervals factor into your code? Perhaps if you can show us some code you are working on, we could provide better help.

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11345/can-mathematica-handle-open-intervals-interval-complements

Comment: Couldn't the language use `Except` to support open endpoints, eg `Interval[{0,Except[1]}]` ==> [0,1). No problem with representation, what about interval computation?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A possible cause of a mental block in this scenario is to think that we need to find a way to include all numbers that are infinitely close to our endpoints. Since we are working on a computer though our numbers are not continuous, so we are actually dealing with a discrete set of numbers. What we need to do is create a new interval where the boundaries are as close as possible to the endpoints given the capability of our computer to differentiate between numbers. Take a look at this:

```
int = Interval[{18.9 (1 + $MachineEpsilon), 21 (1 - $MachineEpsilon)}];
{IntervalMemberQ[int, 18.9], IntervalMemberQ[int, 21]}
```

> `{True, True}`

```
int = Interval[{18.9 (1 + 2 $MachineEpsilon), 21 (1 - 2 $MachineEpsilon)}];
{IntervalMemberQ[int, 18.9], IntervalMemberQ[int, 21]}
```

> `{False, False}`

What this shows is that the capability of `IntervalMemberQ` to distinguish between endpoints is up to a factor of `(1 +- 2 $MachineEpsilon)`. This is also very close to the computer system's ability to differentiate between numbers, which it can do up to a factor of `(1 +- $MachineEpsilon)`. i.e. it is about as good as it's going to get.

Comment: +1)...I don't know why we get `True` in your first example.But I think `ImplicitRegion` can get a excat open interval.