# Operating with real intervals

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, syntax, algebraic-manipulation, intersection, sets

```
If the following intervals are real, 
$A=[-5,3],B=]-3,5[ ,C=]-\infty ,2[$,

how to find the operations but using Mathematica,
$a)(A \cup C)^{c}$,
$b)(C-A)$,
$c)(B-C)^{c}$,
```

I have problems writing the intervals, I searched the forum but what I found does not solve the problem

these are just examples, the idea is to make it more general

(edit :I indent the code but I do not take it

Comment: In your interval notation I presume that `]-3,5[` is the open interval `(-3, 5)` and `[-5, 3]` is the closed interval. Correct?

Comment: [Related](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11345/45411).

Comment: Correct ,open ]a,b[ and closed [a,b] interval

Comment: hi ,aardvark2012 ,, I saw that publication, but how do you define the difference of set and complement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to write your own interval data type with Mathematica. Below is a basic skeleton to build on. Intervals will be repesented by objects with head `interval` (very creative, huh?) wrapped around a sequence of quadruples of the form, e.g., `{a,Less,LessEqual,b}` representing the half open interval $]a,b]$. What we basically need is to

1. write a routine `ToInequality` that takes such an `interval` object a produces a sequence of inequalities wrapped by `Or`.
2. write some routines `ToInterval` that can convert at least simple inequalities into an `interval`.
3. overload `Union`, `Intersection`, and `Complement` to objects with head `interval` by defining a completely new behavior. To this end, we employ `Reduce` and switch off a warning message that occurs when computing with inexact data. It would be great if somebody had a better idea.
4. overload `Format` to objects with head `interval` in order have a nice presentation when an `interval` is printed as output.

This is the code:

```
interval /: ToInequalities[A_interval, x_] := 
 Or @@ Map[a \[Function] Inequality[a[[1]], a[[2]], x, a[[3]], a[[4]]], A]

ToInterval[
   HoldPattern[
    Inequality[a_, s : (Less | LessEqual), x_, t : (Less | LessEqual),
      b_]], x_] := interval[{a, s, t, b}];

ToInterval[Less[a_, x_], x_] := interval[{a, Less, Less, ∞}];
ToInterval[LessEqual[a_, x_], x_] := interval[{a, LessEqual, Less, ∞}];
ToInterval[Greater[x_, a_], x_] := interval[{a, Less, Less, ∞}];
ToInterval[GreaterEqual[x_, a_], x_] := interval[{a, LessEqual, Less, ∞}];

ToInterval[Less[x_, b_], x_] :=  interval[{-∞, Less, Less, b}];
ToInterval[LessEqual[x_, b_], x_] := interval[{-∞, Less, LessEqual, b}];
ToInterval[Greater[b_, x_], x_] := interval[{-∞, Less, Less, b}];
ToInterval[GreaterEqual[b_, x_], x_] := interval[{-∞, Less, LessEqual, b}];

ToInterval[Reals] := interval[{-∞, Less, Less, ∞}];

ToInterval[eq_Or, x_] := Join @@ Map[a \[Function] ToInterval[a, x], eq];

interval /: Intersection[ints__interval] := Module[{x},
   Off[Reduce::ratnz];
   With[{result = 
      ToInterval[
       Reduce[And @@ Map[a \[Function] ToInequalities[a, x], {ints}], 
        x], x]},
    On[Reduce::ratnz];
    result
    ]
   ];

interval /: Union[ints__interval] := Module[{x},
   Off[Reduce::ratnz];
   With[{result = 
      ToInterval[
       Reduce[Or @@ Map[a \[Function] ToInequalities[a, x], {ints}], 
        x], x]},
    On[Reduce::ratnz];
    result
    ]
   ];

interval /: Complement[int_interval, ints__interval] := Module[{x},
   Off[Reduce::ratnz];
   With[{result = ToInterval[
       Reduce[
        And[ToInequalities[int, 
          x], ! (Or @@ 
            Map[a \[Function] ToInequalities[a, x], {ints}])], x],
       x]},
    On[Reduce::ratnz];
    result
    ]
   ];

interval /: Format[int_interval] := 
  Row[{"interval", "[ ", Row[Riffle[
      Map[
       a \[Function] 
        Row[{a[[2]] /. {LessEqual -> "[", Less -> "]"}, a[[1]], ",", 
          a[[4]], a[[3]] /. {LessEqual -> "]", Less -> "["}}],
       List @@ int
       ]
      , " ⋃ "]], " ]"}];
```

Some usage examples: Define two intervals:

```
I1 = interval[{-1/2, LessEqual, LessEqual, 1/2}, {2, Less, LessEqual, 
   3 + 1/2}]
I2 = interval[{0, LessEqual, LessEqual, 1}, {3, LessEqual, Less, 4}]
```

[image]

The newly defined set operations on these intervals:

```
Union[I1, I2]
Intersection[I1, I2]
Complement[I2, I1]
Complement[ ToInterval[Reals], I2]
```

[image]

Some futher interval arithmetics could be implemented similar to the following. I don't have the time to test this thoroughly at the moment, so this will almost surely contain bugs or other shortcomings.

```
interval /: Times[x_?NumericQ, A_interval] := If[x >= 0,
   Map[a \[Function] {a[[1]] x, a[[2]], a[[3]], a[[4]] x}, A],
   Map[a \[Function] {a[[4]] x, a[[3]], a[[2]], a[[1]] x}, 
    Reverse[A]]
   ];

interval /: Plus[x_?NumericQ, A_interval] := 
  Map[a \[Function] {a[[1]] + x, a[[2]], a[[3]], a[[4]] + x}, A];

SetAttributes[IntervalPrecedence, Orderless];
IntervalPrecedence[Less__, LessEqual__] := Less;
IntervalPrecedence[Less__] := Less;
IntervalPrecedence[LessEqual__] := LessEqual;

SetAttributes[IntervalPrecedence2, Orderless];
IntervalPrecedence2[Less__, LessEqual__] := LessEqual;
IntervalPrecedence2[Less__] := Less;
IntervalPrecedence2[LessEqual__] := LessEqual;

interval /: Plus[A_interval, B_interval] := Union @@ Outer[
   {x, y} \[Function] {x[[1]] + y[[1]], 
     IntervalPrecedence[x[[2]], y[[2]]], 
     IntervalPrecedence[x[[3]], y[[3]]], x[[4]] + y[[4]]},
   A, B, 1
   ]

interval /: Times[A_interval, B_interval] := 
 Module[{less, vals, min, max, posmin, posmax},
  Union@Flatten[#, 1] &@Outer[{x, y} \[Function] (
      vals = Flatten[#, 1]&@Outer[Times, x[[{1, 4}]], y[[{1, 4}]], 1];
      less = Flatten[#, 1]&@Outer[IntervalPrecedence, x[[{2, 3}]], y[[{2, 3}]], 1];
      min = Min[vals];
      max = Max[vals];
      posmin = Flatten[Position[vals, min, 1]];
      posmax = Flatten[Position[vals, max, 1]];
      {min, IntervalPrecedence2 @@ less[[posmin]], 
       IntervalPrecedence2 @@ less[[posmax]], max}
      )
    , A, B, 1
    ]
  ]
```

**Final remarks**

Admittedly, this is very, very basic and several things had to be improved for every day use. For a start, the `Format` could be nicened considerably, e.g., with expanding brackets.
Moreover, this certainly does not cover all the cases that may occur in practice.

Comment: Henrik Schumacher very good  , as would be done with the subtraction of intervals?

Comment: @susydiaz I edited my post. Now `A-B` should produce the interval arithmetric subtraction.

Answer (score 5):

You may use functions from the [Inequalities](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/Inequalities.html) and [Logic & Boolean Algebra](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/LogicAndBooleanAlgebra.html) guides.  There is also [`Interval`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Interval.html) but as of version 11.2 it only does closed intervals.

With

```
{a, b, c} = {-5 <= \[FormalX] <= 3, -3 < \[FormalX] < 5, -Infinity < \[FormalX] < 2};

NumberLinePlot[{a, b, c}, \[FormalX], PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Then with some boolean algebra

```
NumberLinePlot[
 Reduce /@ {
   ! (a || b),
   c && ! a,
   ! (b && ! c)
   },
 \[FormalX], PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Hope this helps.

Comment: wow, yes I need that, finally as you calculate
    $\left ( A \bigcap B^{c} \right )-(B \Delta (C-A) )$